# Tool for Viewing Formatted HTML Source Code in Browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, web-applications, browser, safari

I'm developing a web scraping tool in Python, and I need to get intimately acquainted with the functions of various HTML tags on certain sites. Unfortunately, the "view source" that Chrome, Firefox, and Safari offer does not output very well formatted HTML source code -- it tends to place a huge number of tags on the same line. Do the browsers offer any plugins that may be able to clean things up a bit, or do I need to get/develop some kind of tool in Python that takes dirty HTML as input and outputs cleanly formatted HTML?

Comment: ^^ source code is different and inspect element is different f12

Answer (score 2):

Since I work primarily with Chrome, the best examples I can think of are [Code Formatter (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/code-formatter/deecjbhfakhcegonhediiniinjdgmfie?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog.)

This isn't automatic; you have to copy and paste the entire page into the app. Also the app window is small (this unalterable to my knowledge), but relatively effective.

...and  [JavaScript and CSS Beautifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-and-css-code-b/iiglodndmmefofehaibmaignglbpdald?hl=en)

Much more effective and clean, but only works, as the title suggests, with .Js and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox you can select (highlight - I am writing for beginners also) the text, and once it is selected, release the left mouse button and right click within the selected area and choose "View selection source."  You can then copy the highlighted text and paste it.

My composite example:
[View selection source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEaUP.gif)